# How to get Lucene's retrieveTerms working?

Tags: java, apache, lucene, morelikethis

I'm trying to leverage the retrieveTerms method from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/queries/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queries/mlt/MoreLikeThis.java and I'm hitting a NullPointerException on the following line

```
final Fields vectors = ir.getTermVectors(docNum);
```

I don't exactly know why this is happening, so any explanation would be awesome.  For clarity, I'll post the whole method below, as well as the earlier declaration of ir.

```
private static IndexReader ir;


public static PriorityQueue<Object[]> retrieveTerms(int docNum) throws IOException {
Map<String, Int> termFreqMap = new HashMap<>();
for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
  final Fields vectors = ir.getTermVectors(docNum);
  final Terms vector;
  if (vectors != null) {
    vector = vectors.terms(fieldName);
  } else {
    vector = null;
  }

  // field does not store term vector info
  if (vector == null) {
    Document d = ir.document(docNum);
    StorableField[] fields = (StorableField[]) d.getFields(fieldName);
    for (StorableField field : fields) {
      final String stringValue = field.stringValue();
      if (stringValue != null) {
        addTermFrequencies(new StringReader(stringValue), termFreqMap, fieldName);
      }
    }
  } else {
    addTermFrequencies(termFreqMap, vector);
  }
}

return createQueue(termFreqMap);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I had not correctly initialized my index reader.  Got it working by doing so!